# Insert a digit after the nth character/number to form a longer integer

Tags: python

from file id15.txt with the following content

```
420303790908543　aaa
451423910118759　bbb
350524860924609　ccc
```

I'm trying to add `19` after every 6th number to make the total count 17 digits.

I thought about splitting the digits into a list  `digits = str(id).split(",")` then adding the new digits but I haven't been successful

The code below is where I intend to implement it.

```
def id15218(id15):
    xishu = [7, 9, 10, 5, 8, 4, 2, 1, 6, 3, 7, 9, 10, 5, 8, 4, 2]
    yushu = [1, 0, 'X', 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
    count = 0
    for i in range(17):
        count += int(id) * xishu[i]
    last = count % 11
    print('New Identification no: %s%s' % (id, yushu[last]))


n = int(input())
with open('id15.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for i in range(n):
        line = file.readline()
        id = int(str(line)[:-4])
        id15218(id)
```

Comment: what is the use of `n = int(input())`? and what is `xishu` and  `yushu` for?

Comment: `n = int(input())` is used to get a certain number of inputs from the external file. the file id15.txt has around 100 inputs. `xishu` and `yushu` it's just Chinese to English translations of labeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the number in strings, add the number you need as a string and convert back to `int`

`id = int(str(line[:6]) + "19" + str(line[6:15]))`

And you don't need an additional function for this.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with an entirely numeric approach (which is much faster than converting numbers to strings):

```
>>> n = 420303790908543
>>> res = n // 10**9 * 10**11 + 19 * 10**9 + n % 10**9
>>> res
42030319790908543
```

Answer (score 0):

I make some changes into the method id15218 and I split the line with space instead of ([:-4]):

```
def id15218(id15):
    rest_id = id15[7:]
    new_id =id15[0:6]
    #step 2 because 19 is two digits, iterate over the diff of len
    for i in range(0,17-len(id15),2):
        new_id = new_id + "19"
    return int(new_id+rest_id)

n = int(input())
with open('id15.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for i in range(n):
        line = file.readline()
        id1 = str(line.split(" ")[0])
        id15218(id1)
```